# "str" object has no attricute 'c' error in fastapi while implimenting sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

I am learning FastAPI from freecodingcamp. I ran into to a problem:

This is my file structure:

```
App
|_ database.py
|_ main.py
|_ models.py
|_ __init__.py
```

---

This is my `main.py` file

```py
from fastapi import Body, Depends, FastAPI,Response,status,HTTPException
from fastapi.params import Body
from pydantic import BaseModel
from random import randrange
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import time
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from database import Base
import models
from database import engine,SessionLocal
# from requests import Response
app = FastAPI()

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

class postparam(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content:str
    Published: bool =True
    
while True:
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(host= 'localhost',database='FastApi',user='postgres',password='2580',cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print('Database connection Established!!')
        break
    except Exception as error:
        print("connection to database failed !!")
        print('Error: ',error)
        time.sleep(2)

    

@app.get("/sql")
async def root(db:Session =Depends(get_db)):
    return {"message":"this is a sample fastapi"}
```

this is how my `database.py` file looks like:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:2580@localhost/Fastpi"  #use os.join from local variable
# SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://user:password@postgresserver/db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

This is how my `models.py` file looks like:

```py
# from tokenize import String
from sqlalchemy import Column,Integer,String,Boolean
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import null
from database import Base


class Post(Base):
    __table__ = 'posts'
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key= True,nullable=False)
    name = Column(String,nullable =False)
    content = Column(String,nullable = False)
    published = Column(Boolean,default= False)
```

[image: This is my output in Powershell]

Comment: Do not include code or output as images, images are not searchable, not accessible to those who have trouble seeing, requires the reader to swap back and forth and can't be copy and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Post` model you're overriding `__table__` - this is an internal value used by SQLAlchemy.

You're looking for `__tablename__`:

```py
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = Column(Integer,primary_key= True,nullable=False)
    name = Column(String,nullable =False)
    content = Column(String,nullable = False)
    published = Column(Boolean,default= False)
```